# php yii2 form field depend on out-of-form field

Tags: php, forms, yii2

I am searching for a solution to my problem in php/yii2. I am using DependDropdown widget.

To guide : My currently working (lets say 'Application') table has columns:

```
1.  Id    
2.  student_id
3.  university_id    [....rest....]
```

In my ActiveForm I have a dropdownlist with lets say students names. They are grouped in model, but in case if there would be students with the same name and surname I want to add Depend Dropdown with Personal Identify Number to choose specific person. But column with this number is from another table than my `$model`. Application table has `student_id` column, and I want to get that student_id to ActiveForm , but by searching it from my Dropdown with personal ID. I try to show it on example

`<droplist with names >`
I choose for example Carl Dickens

`<droplist with Personal number>`

**Case 1:**  Okay, in DB students table there is only 1 Carl Dickens. So there is only 1 number to choose from droplist

**Case 2:** There are some Carls Dickens in DB. All Carl Dickens personal numbers are dropped to dropdown list, so u can choose correct one by it

`<droplist with Personal number>` is not a column from `$model` (Application) table, and that's my problem in ActiveForm. Can somebody help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please declare $personal_number as a variable in your model

```
class Application extends ActiveRecord
{

public $personal_number;


.....
}
```